# HOW check if the file is updated？

Tags: python, string, file, list

## 1: HOW check if the file is updated？(newsize VS oldsize)?

## 2: if the file is updated get it's name

Comment: What do you want to do? Keep track of the filesize of a certain file? Your question is too much of talking about your solution, and not about what you want to achieve. That way it is difficult to come up with an adavanced proposal.

Comment: Check the directory the file is updated if the update to update the contents of the print, and print the file name.

Comment: Well then if do what if then file go while file do if? Did you understand a word? Sorry, but this does not help. If your english is not good enough, try to split your explanation into several bits, like 1: check if the file is updated, 2: if the file is updated get it's name, 3: print the content of the file; something like this. I recommend doing that as an edit to your original post, as it will not work well in a comment. Maybe splitting it up that way even helps you to get to a solution by yourself...

Comment: My English is really bad, I used Google Translate.I try your method, thank you!

Comment: Why did you remove the code? If you have another question please open a new question.

Answer (score 0):

Check the content of `fp`. The way the code looks, all the lines must start with:

```
200#
```

It's not clear to me why because the rest of the code looks correct, so the error must be elsewhere.